# Getting "Invlalid minute value = ?" from java @Schedule annotation

Tags: java, ejb, java-annotations

Got an issue today when trying to use a Java @Schedule annotation on one of my methods. Error is as follows:

```
Severe:   Exception while deploying the app [MyApp-ear] : Error processing EjbDescriptor
java.lang.RuntimeException: ScheduleManager: Invalid schedule defined on method sendEmail(): Invalid minute value: ?
at org.glassfish.ejb.deployment.util.EjbBundleValidator.accept(EjbBundleValidator.java:351)
at org.glassfish.ejb.deployment.descriptor.EjbDescriptor.visit(EjbDescriptor.java:2855)
at org.glassfish.ejb.deployment.descriptor.EjbDescriptor.visit(EjbDescriptor.java:2843)
at org.glassfish.ejb.deployment.util.EjbBundleValidator.accept(EjbBundleValidator.java:115)
at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.BundleDescriptor.visit(BundleDescriptor.java:627)
at org.glassfish.ejb.deployment.descriptor.EjbBundleDescriptorImpl.visit(EjbBundleDescriptorImpl.java:767)
at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.util.ApplicationValidator.accept(ApplicationValidator.java:121)
at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.BundleDescriptor.visit(BundleDescriptor.java:627)
at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.ApplicationArchivist.validate(ApplicationArchivist.java:703)
at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.ApplicationArchivist.openWith(ApplicationArchivist.java:248)
at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.ApplicationFactory.openWith(ApplicationFactory.java:232)
at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.processDOL(DolProvider.java:189)
at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:223)
at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:91)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.loadDeployer(ApplicationLifecycle.java:882)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.setupContainerInfos(ApplicationLifecycle.java:822)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:378)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:220)
at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:487)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:189)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:466)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:169)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:539)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:593)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:573)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

My method declaration looks like this:

```
@Schedule(minute = "∗/5")
public void sendEmail() {
  //Send email here
}
```

Any idea what could be causing this? I've used this many a time and never had any problems but mostly used the "dayOfMonth" attribute. I found the expression that I was looking for on the Oracle Docs for @Schedule to run every 5 minutes on the hour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The * char was invalid, but you already noticed that :)

### Important hint: your scheduling is still wrong!

When not specifying any of the annotation's parameters, it will fall back to the default value. The **default value for `hour` is 0**, meaning that your scheduled task will run **every 5 minutes from 00:05 to 00:55**, and then be idle for the next 23 hours.

To fix this, also specify the hours as *:

```
@Schedule(hour = "*", minute = "*/5")
```

See default values in `Schedule`:

```
public @interface Schedule {

    String second() default "0";
    String minute() default "0";
    String hour() default "0";
```

Comment: jip I noticed that when I got it deployed and it wasn't running every 5 minutes on the hour. :) already fixed it exactly as in your suggestion. I am however sure that others will find this useful as well. I'll mark yours as the correct answer instead as it contains much more detail. Thanks man. Cheers

Comment: We had that problem some months ago, sometimes the task was running, and sometimes not. Turned out in the end that it was a problem with the defaults, it's really easy to fall into this trap :)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a silly copy-paste issue from the Oracle Docs website. It copied a '∗' instead of a '*' which caused the JVM to crash at runtime. Do not copy from the Oracle Docs website, lesson learned.

Well I hope this saves someone 30 minutes in the future should they run into the same problem.

Regards,